# Get rid of gap when hiding the toolbar and swiping to get to a new tab

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-recyclerview

I would like to copy the behavior of the Google play store where they automatically scroll content up when the tab bars are hidden, see [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BziVa.png).

I hide the bars by overriding the onScrollChanged within a RecyclerView, something like this:

```
headerTranslationY = Math.min(0, Math.max(-toolbarHeight, currentTranslation + justScrolled));
mHeaderView.setTranslationY(headerTranslationY);
```

If I swipe down and move to the next tab (either by swiping or clicking) the content of the second tab has a gap since it didn't know that it should move up along with the first tab. Example is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o80E.png). Google play on the other hand seems to get this perfect and I am not sure how, [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BziVa.png).

I have tried calling mRecyclerView.scrollTo(x,y) or mRecyclerView.smoothScrollTo(x,y) within ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener, but this has a very ugly effect with lists constantly moving around.

How can I get rid of this padding to make it like google play?